# execute Queue job without paasing by my ViewComposer i share with (*) using pm2

Tags: laravel, queue, traits, jobs, pm2

## trying to prevent queued job from passing by ViewComposer in laravel using pm2.

> > Problem : setCookie has not been applied because (i think ) there is no session from extern calls access (pm2).
>
> ### let me explain:
>
> > also sharing with you this part of my app.
> >
> > I have a queued job that sends dynamic emails (templates and mail params)
> >     in my *ServiceController*,
> >     also, am sharing needed data with all view when returning to any of them,
> >     so I created a *ViewComposer* called by any view(*) in *AppServiceProvider*, inside this *ViewComposer*, am using a trait that uses many traits too, to collect data I need for views.
> >
> > - when I navigate in my application everything looks fine.
> > - when implementing any task that uses queued jobs, in my case sending an email:
> >
> >   > when I run *php artisan queue:work* everything works fine too and I receive emails.
> >
> > ### BUT
> >
> > - when I use *pm2* deamon which calls that queue it fires an exception :
> >       (*setCookie has not been applied*) related to that trait I use in view composer.
> >
> > *I know it's hard for me to explain it, but I really need some help here.*
> >
> > ### here is my code :
> >
> > - pm2 path : /  (server root)
> > - app path :/prod
> > - shared hosting with ssh.

### 1. AppServiceProvider

```
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
       public function register()
       {
         Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
       }

       public function boot()
       {
          view()->composer('*',
          'App\Http\ViewComposers\MasterComposer');
       }
    }
```

### 2. WebsiteComposer:

```
    namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
    use App\Website;
    use other_traits;

     trait WebsiteComposer 
     {
        use other_traits;
       protected function Get_Website(Request $request) 
       {
         //some code by calling other traits;
         // $results= get client websitestuff;

         $this->website= $results;

       }
     }
```

### 3. MasterComposer:

```
     namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;
     use Illuminate\View\View;
     use Illuminate\Http\Request;

     class MasterComposer
     {
        use WebsiteComposer; 
        public $web=[];

        public function __construct()
        {
        }

        public function compose(View $view)
        { 
          //to prevent external views( email templates located in 
          //views/emails from passing by getting website process...

           if(!starts_with($view->getName(), 'emails'))
           {
             //here where exception fired using pm2 

             $this->Get_Website(request());
             $this->web=$this->website;
           }

           View::share('website', $this->web);
        }
      }
```

### 4. ServiceContorller:

## (the Start of the process)

```
       // POST PROCESS then Calling this function :

       public function EmailDispatcher($data,Request $request)
       {
          //some code...
          dispatch(function () use ($data) {
          dispatch(new GuestMailerJob($data));
          });

         return redirect('somview');
       }
```

### 5. GuestMailerJob:

```
   namespace App\Jobs;
   use App\Mail\GuestMailer;
   // needed uses...

   class GuestMailerJob implements ShouldQueue
   {
     use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, 
     SerializesModels,GuestMailer;

       protected $data;
       public $tries = 3;
       public $timeout = 10;

       public function retryUntil()
       {
          return now()->addSeconds(12);
       }

       public function __construct(Array $data)
       {
          $this->data=$data;
       }

       public function handle()
       {
          $this->sendEmail($this->data);
       }
   }
```

### 6. GuestMailer:

```
   namespace App\Mail;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Mail;

   trait GuestMailer 
   {
      protected function sendEmail(array $all) 
      { 
          $toview = array( 

            'title' => $all["title"],
            'other_attributes' => $all["other_attributes"]
          );

           Mail::send( [$all["template"]=> $all['view']],$toview,

           function ($message)  use($all)
           { 
             $message->from( $all['from'],$all['nameFrom'] );
             $message->subject( $all['subject'] );
             //other params...
            }

          });
      }
    }
```

### 7. pm2 executed file : mail-worker.yml

```
         //located in: (/prod)
         //mail-worker.yml content:


           apps:
             - name: mail-worker
             script: artisan
             exec_mode: fork
             interpreter: php
             instances: 1
           args:
             - queue:work
             - --tries=1
             - --sleep=1
```

### 8 : artisan Cleaning

```
       all php artisan cleaners are implemented

       ex : php artisan clear-compiled
            php artisan queue:restart
```

### 9 : pm2  Configuration :

```
           pm2 start mail-worker.yml
           pm2 monit
```

### 10 - pm2 state :

```
       id    name            mode   reload   status   cpu   memory

       0     mail-worker     fork   1        online   0%    6.5mp
```

> > it's working  with php artisan queue:work / listen
> >     but with pm2 here is the exception.

### pm2 Result :

> > Whoops\Run::handleError("Trait method setCookie has not been applied,
> >      /app_base_path/PRODMAAN/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Run.ph  x
> >      Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()                                                 [internal]:0

### failed_Jobs result :

> > Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: App\Jobs\GuestMailerJob has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.

## what is the problem ?

> thank you for any advice about the code structure too.